# SimFinger Move to the Middle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I have an Question on SimFinger. SimFinger is an application that makes simulator take videos (Clever Idea). The only issue is SimFinger moves all the way to the left of the screen. Could we move SimFinger to he middle to get a 16:9 ratio. You can install SimFinger here at GitHub: https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger. Thanks for your Help (Take a look at the Project and tell what part of the code I need to change to make SimFinger in the middle of the screen). [image]

Comment: Just to tell you guys I got all those fake application (App Store, Messages, etc..) from SimFinger :)

Comment: What exactly is that application? Screen recorder?

Comment: It takes the iPhone simulator and put an iPhone on it to look like an real iPhone...

Comment: Have you looked at the github source yourself? What have you tried? And have you tried posting an issue on that github page (in which you're contacting the authors and interested parties) rather than Stack Overflow? Also, the author listed his email address there, so why not email him directly?

Comment: Down Voter: The git hub link blog was down...

Comment: I down-voted your question as didn't exhibit much research effort. You say that the link to his blog is down, and that's fine, but (a) ACB seemed to find it ok (presumably googled it); and (b) as I suggested above, you could direct your question to the "Issues" section of the github page. If you edit the question to enumerate the research you had done and what you had tried, I'm more than happy to change my vote.

Comment: Yes, the git hub link is down and I got it from google. Just searched for SimFinger and this was there as one of the results.

Comment: @Rob Sorry I am new to Stack-Overflow and I will keep your comments in mind next time I make a new Question :)

Comment: @iProgrammed No problem. We've all been there. I appreciate your taking my comments in the spirit intended, namely one of constructive criticism. I hope you enjoy Stack Overflow and get as much out of it as I have. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked [their blog](http://www.iphonesat.com/not-your-average-iphone-screencast-2/) and this is what mentioned there,

> Some notes: you probably want to hide your Dock. SimFinger currently
>   locks itself to the lower-left of the screen. **If you launch SimFinger
>   with iPhone Simulator already running, it will automatically
>   reposition the iPhone Simulator. If they ever get out of whack, just
>   go to Control – Reposition iPhone Simulator Window** (you’ll need
>   Accessibility enabled in the System Preferences for this to work).

Try it out and reply to them if this doesn't help. So there are no ways to move sim finger, but it should automatically align with simulator.